# Remote Offer: Freelancer Contract with Benefits

Tags: freelancing, remote-work

I've just received an offer for a senior management position with a well-funded start-up based in a different EU country in which I can work remotely.

The offer letter states there are paid vacation, sick-days and maternity/paternity but also that the position is under a 'Freelance' basis with six-months probation.

From my understanding, there's no legal obligation and would be 'generosity' on the employers behalf. Similarly, as a Freelance there'd be limited security in terms of termination periods and so forth?

Comment: Ask them what they mean by "freelance". Specifically, are you going to be an "employee", legally speaking.

Comment: Where are you located and where is the company located? That's going to have a major impact on what's possible legally, even within the EU.

Answer (score 3):

A "freelancer" is self-employed by definition. Your benefits are not something a company would be involved in. If they are involved in your benefits, you are not an actual freelancer and what they are offering is probably illegal in the EU (but IANAL and this is not legal advice).

E.g., the German version of the IRS would crack down hard on this scheme as it is a common indicator of *Scheinselbständigkeit* (tax evasion and/or wage dumping by not registering someone as an employee who has all the duties of an employee).

Comment: You would be surprised at the extent of differences between countries on this. Also, I thought *Schwarzarbeit* was typically unreported work for cash without any kind of formal contractual relationship. Wouldn't what the OP describes more typically be called * Scheinselbständigkeit*? AFAIK, working for one company or getting additional benefits isn't actually the main issue. Legally what matters is the amount of control your employer/client has on the way you carry out your work, i.e. whether the employer exercises the *Weisungsrecht* that is typical of employment.

Comment: @Relaxed Well, AFAIU *Scheinselbständigkeit* is a form of *Schwarzarbeit* ...

Answer (score 0):

Establishing payroll and fulfilling all legal obligations associated with employment in a different country is complicated and there are still significant differences between countries. Hiring *bona fide* employees might even be downright impossible without a local legal entity, *even in the EU*. Consequently, a lot of remote-first companies or startups hiring across Europe rely on “HR services providers” that work with local partners to work out the contractual details.

Depending on your location, what you get might be more akin to freelancing / self-employment or some in-between solution like “*portage salarial*” in France or umbrella companies in the UK. You might also get a contract with a separate business (sometimes called an employer of record) acting on behalf of the company you will actually be working for. I am also aware of some businesses that just avoid recruiting in specific countries, presumably because they think such schemes come with too much uncertainty and potential liability.

What your exact rights and obligations are differ depending on the details and the legal ramification are not always completely clear. In general, you are right that they are likely to be less protective of the worker than regular employment, at least in the most protective countries. Depending on the details and jurisdiction, it's also possible that what is being offered could run afoul of local regulations against false self-employment (but the typical gig economy job is probably much worse in this respect and it has been going on for years).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind wasting sometime, just talk to them about everything down to the last moment so you can have the chance to get an inspection of the actual contract.